# Deploying unity 3d app to hololens apps fails with code -2147483645

Tags: visual-studio, hololens

I recently upgraded my unity 3d app from unity version `5.6.0` to `5.6.1` and `holotoolkit-unity` from `1.5.6` to `1.5.7`.

Now, whenever I build the app and attempt to deploy it to the device via `Visual Studio 2017`, I get the following error:

```
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'c:\data\Programs\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.2.1_1.1.25129.1_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\entrypoint\LabanotationAR.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\System.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'c:\data\Programs\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.3.1_1.1.25129.1_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\UnityPlayer.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\WinRTBridge.winmd'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\BridgeInterface.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\System.Collections.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\UnityEngine.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\Assembly-CSharp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\System.Threading.Tasks.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\System.IO.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\WinRTLegacy.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\UnityEngine.UI.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\System.ObjectModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\UnityEngine.Networking.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\UnityEngine.HoloLens.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\nunit.framework.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\System.Reflection.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\UnityEngine.Analytics.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\System.Globalization.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\System.Net.Primitives.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\System.Private.Networking.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\System.Xml.XDocument.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\System.Private.Uri.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\System.Text.Encoding.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\UnityEngine.VR.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\System.Threading.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Loading native plugins

  Loading MicStreamSelector.dll

  Loading SharingClient.dll

  Loading SpatialUnderstanding.dll

  Loading PlaneFinding.dll

Module information:
 Built with Compiler Ver '190023918'
 Built from '5.6/release' branch
 Version is '5.6.1f1 (2860b30f0b54)'
 Debug build
 Application type 'D3D11'
 Used 'UWP'

 OS 'Windows 10 (10.0.14393)'

PlayerConnection initialized from C:/Data/Users/DefaultAccount/AppData/Local/DevelopmentFiles/LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr/Data (debug = 0)

PlayerConnection initialized network socket : 0.0.0.0 55008

Multi-casting "[IP] 172.30.0.203 [Port] 55008 [Flags] 2 [Guid] 2978211851 [EditorId] 4294967295 [Version] 1048832 [Id] MetroPlayerX86(HoloLens-UAO3C) [Debug] 0" to [225.0.0.222:54997]...

Started listening to [0.0.0.0:55008]

Player data archive not found at `C:/Data/Users/DefaultAccount/AppData/Local/DevelopmentFiles/LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr/Data/data.unity3d`, using local filesystem
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1

Direct3D:

    Version:  Direct3D 11.0 [level 11.1]

    Renderer: HoloLens Graphics (ID=0x22b0)

    Vendor:   Intel

    VRAM:     604 MB

Initialize engine version: 5.6.1f1 (2860b30f0b54)

'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\UnityEngineProxy.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\System.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'LabanotationAR.exe' (CoreCLR: CoreCLR_UWP_Domain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\LabanotationARVS.Debug_x86.kurtr\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
The following GlobalManagers were stripped from the build (Either because they're not used or not supported on this platform):
  NetworkManager
  MasterServerInterface
  UnityAdsManager
  ClusterInputManager
  CrashReportManager

If your machine has multiple graphics adapters, Unity may have created a WindowContext on the wrong adapter. If you experience a black screen when playing, please restart the Editor.

(Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/VR/VRDevice.cpp Line: 184)


UnloadTime: 25.033651 ms

WinRTScriptingObjectWrapper::InternalAddRef Reference Count cannot be zero

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/ScriptingBackend/DotNet/ScriptingApi_DotNet.cpp Line: 661)


The program '[3492] LabanotationAR.exe' has exited with code -2147483645 (0x80000003).
```

IF anybody could give some pointers in how to go about debugging this error message, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a Unity issue fixed for a future release. This should be releasing in the next Beta update.

[Source](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/wsa-worldanchorstore-dot-getasync-throws-an-exception-when-starting-deployed-hololens-app-built)

Comment: Good to know. I've been working with them on Unity Answers and when I showed them the debug log for managed code, they stopped replying :).